# When is onServiceFault called in milo opc ua client?

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I hava a milo opc ua client and added a fault listener with client.addFaultListener(this) and I have overridden the method onServiceFault (so that it implements ServiceFaultListener).

When I shutdown my opc ua server I only get a messages from milo:
[WARNING][org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.cli] [4] Keep Alive failureCount=1 exceeds failuresAllowed=0
but my fault listener is not executed.

In what cases is the onServiceFault listener executed by milo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s called when the client actually receives a ServiceFault response from the server, which can happen in a variety of scenarios, one of which being that the server doesn’t support a service that you’ve called.

Shutting down the server like you did should result in `onSessionInactive` being invoked on any SessionListener you’ve added to the client.

Comment: The hint with the session and onSessionInactive is great, I can now monitor the state of my connection...Thank you Kevin!

Comment: @AndreasVogler just be aware that the callback is purely informational, for monitoring the state as you suggested, and that the client will automatically attempt to reconnect and re-establish a session indefinitely until you call `client.disconnect()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I need it to re-establish subscriptions - those are lost when e.g. the server restarts. Btw.: do I have to clean up somehow the old subscriptions? currently I do a: subscription.deleteMonitoredItems(subscription.getMonitoredItems()); ... but I am not sure if this is really needed, or maybe I have to do more than that?

Comment: You don't need to clean up old subscriptions. If they couldn't be recovered/transferred then there's no reason to believe a call to delete the items would have any success. The proper place to re-create your subscriptions after a reconnect would be when the `SubscriptionListener#onSubscriptionTransferFailed` callback notifies you the subscriptions couldn't be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can now answer my question by myself: for example it is called when the servers connection is lost and milo does a reconnect but the transfer of subscriptions fails and when this invalid subscription is used afterwards, then milo will execute a ServiceFault like this with status Bad_SubscriptionIdInvalid.

```
ServiceFault(responseHeader=ResponseHeader(timestamp=DateTime{utcTime=132556030188286769, javaDate=Wed Jan 20 08:56:58 CET 2021}, requestHandle=116, serviceResult=StatusCode{name=Bad_SubscriptionIdInvalid, value=0x80280000, quality=bad}, serviceDiagnostics=null, stringTable=[], additionalHeader=ExtensionObject{encoded=ByteString{bytes=null}, encodingId=NodeId{ns=0, id=0}}))
```